# Legendre transform of Gaussian function?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to perform a legendre transform on $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, but I am getting stuck rearranging df/dx for x=?.

My work so far is;

$
df/dx=-2xe^{-x^2}=s
$
Then,
$
ln(-s/2)=ln(x)(-x^2)
$
But how now to invert to get x(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

$$
y = x e^x ~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~ x = W(y) \tag{1}
$$

The problem of finding the Lengendre's transform of $f(x)$ requires finding the minimum of

$$
g_p(x) = p x - f(x) 
$$

or equivalently

$$
p + 2 xe^{-x^2} = 0 ~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~ -2x^2e^{-2x^2} = -\frac{p^2}{2} \tag{2}
$$

and by using Eq. (1) this can be inverted as

$$
-2x^2 = W(-p^2/2) \tag{3}
$$

From here you can calculate

$$
x(p) = \pm i 2^{-1/2}W^{1/2}(-p^2/2)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I was investigating the lambert function when your answer came through! :D

Comment: @AngusTheMan Happy to help